Recursive CTE query runs indefinitely when joining two CTEs
I have two Common Table Expressions (CTEs) in an Oracle SQL query. Both CTEs (CTE_CID and CTE_BEN_DT) return results quickly when executed separately. However, when I join them and add a WHERE clause, the query runs indefinitely and never finishes.
Here's my query structure:
WITH CTE_CID AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_RESULT 
    WHERE NAMT >= 0 
      AND HAMT > 0 
      AND PAT_MT_VAL IS NOT NULL
),
CTE_BEN_DT (OCLAIM_ID, BEN_DT, APP_ID, RPER_ID) AS (
    SELECT SAD.OCLAIM_ID, SA.BEN_DT, SAD.APP_ID, SA.RPER_ID
    FROM app SA
    INNER JOIN app_dis SAD ON SAD.APP_ID = SA.APP_ID
    INNER JOIN CTE_CID CC ON CC.PA_ID = SA.PA_ID
    WHERE SA.APP_ID = CC.APP_ID
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT SAD.OCLAIM_ID, SA.BEN_DT, SAD.APP_ID, SA.RPER_ID
    FROM app SA
    INNER JOIN app_dis SAD ON SAD.APP_ID = SA.APP_ID
    INNER JOIN CTE_BEN_DT S ON S.OCLAIM_ID = SA.APP_ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_CID CCI
JOIN CTE_BEN_DT CBD ON CCI.HEB_ID = CBD.RPER_ID
WHERE CBD.OCLAIM_ID IS NULL;

CTE_CID returns 1,617 records.
CTE_BEN_DT returns 1,679 records.
When executed separately, both CTEs return results quickly.
The final SELECT joining these CTEs never finishes.
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_CID CCI
JOIN CTE_BEN_DT CBD ON CCI.HEB_ID = CBD.RPER_ID
WHERE CBD.OCLAIM_ID IS NULL;

Question:

What could be causing this query to run indefinitely?

Are there any performance optimization techniques or indexing
strategies I can apply to improve this?

Is there a better approach to handle recursive CTEs in Oracle to
avoid this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.



Do you really have a table in your data base called CTE_RESULT?  Or is there something you're not telling us?

@ChrisMaurer Yes, CTE_RESULT is another CTE in my query. The performance issue arises specifically with the two CTEs I shared, so I focused on those in the query provided.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment we have no way of replicating the issue and, if we did, no way to know what a "correct" solution looks like.

You can try to rewrite it as a hierarchical query:
WITH CTE_CID AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_RESULT 
    WHERE NAMT >= 0 
      AND HAMT > 0 
      AND PAT_MT_VAL IS NOT NULL
),
CTE_BEN_DT (OCLAIM_ID, BEN_DT, APP_ID, RPER_ID) AS (
  SELECT SAD.OCLAIM_ID,
         SA.BEN_DT,
         SAD.APP_ID,
         SA.RPER_ID
  FROM   app SA
         INNER JOIN app_dis SAD ON SAD.APP_ID = SA.APP_ID
  START WITH EXISTS(
           SELECT 1
           FROM   CTE_CID CC
           WHERE  CC.PA_ID = SA.PA_ID
           AND    SA.APP_ID = CC.APP_ID
         )
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR SAD.OCLAIM_ID = SA.APP_ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM   CTE_CID CCI
       JOIN CTE_BEN_DT CBD
       ON CCI.HEB_ID = CBD.RPER_ID
WHERE  CBD.OCLAIM_ID IS NULL;

Note: Untested as we do not have any sample data to test against.

If both run quickly but when joined run slowly, this means Oracle is merging the views together and choosing an nonoptimal join path. Without knowing anything about your data model or data, my off-the-cuff suggestion is to simply force Oracle to run each view separately and join them without merging them. You can do that with a few hints (fourth line to the bottom, between /*+ and */
WITH CTE_CID AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_RESULT 
    WHERE NAMT >= 0 
      AND HAMT > 0 
      AND PAT_MT_VAL IS NOT NULL
),
CTE_BEN_DT (OCLAIM_ID, BEN_DT, APP_ID, RPER_ID) AS (
    SELECT SAD.OCLAIM_ID, SA.BEN_DT, SAD.APP_ID, SA.RPER_ID
    FROM app SA
    INNER JOIN app_dis SAD ON SAD.APP_ID = SA.APP_ID
    INNER JOIN CTE_CID CC ON CC.PA_ID = SA.PA_ID
    WHERE SA.APP_ID = CC.APP_ID
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT SAD.OCLAIM_ID, SA.BEN_DT, SAD.APP_ID, SA.RPER_ID
    FROM app SA
    INNER JOIN app_dis SAD ON SAD.APP_ID = SA.APP_ID
    INNER JOIN CTE_BEN_DT S ON S.OCLAIM_ID = SA.APP_ID
)
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(CCI CBD) NO_MERGE(CCI) NO_MERGE(CBD) */ * 
FROM CTE_CID CCI
JOIN CTE_BEN_DT CBD ON CCI.HEB_ID = CBD.RPER_ID
WHERE CBD.OCLAIM_ID IS NULL;

That will likely resolve your issue. If it doesn't, the next thing to check is to ensure that either HEB_ID is unique in CCI or that RPER_ID is unique in CBD. At least one side of a join must be unique on the join keys. If it isn't naturally already so given the structure of cte_result and app, then you'll want to use aggregation (group by) in the CTEs to force uniqueness on the join key in at least one of them.
